# What does 'to wind up' mean in 'to wind up through steep hills'?

Tags: word-meaning, british-english

What does 'to wind up' mean in 'to wind up through steep hills'? Is it the same meaning that 'to wind up in steep heels'? Thank you in advance.

Comment: denise, welcome to the site! Actually, your question would benefit from more context: where did you find this expression, do you have more text? I will attempt an answer, but to be really sure, we need context...

Comment: Hills?  Heels?  If there is confusion over these two words, a dictionary would clear it up. Or is the question about "wind up through"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about a pathway or road that winds up through steep hills. It means that the pathway or road goes up through steep hills in a winding or repeatedly turning way.